# Spurious @ symbol at start of bash prompt in Debian Jessie

Tags: bash, prompt, readline

As of late, and without my deliberately doing anything to make it happen, my Bash prompt has an [at sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_symbol) (i.e. `@`) prepended to it. This did not previously happen. Nor can I see anything in my `~/.bashrc` that seems as though it ought to be making this happen.

This is on Debian Jessie GNU/Linux, using GNU Bash.

For example, my current Bash sessions look like this:

```
@sampablokuper@debianbox:~$ python3
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct  8 2014, 13:14:40) 
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
@>>> 1+2
3
@>>> exit()
@sampablokuper@debianbox:~$
```

whereas originally, they would have looked like this:

```
sampablokuper@debianbox:~$ python3
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct  8 2014, 13:14:40) 
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 1+2
3
>>> exit()
sampablokuper@debianbox:~$
```

Here are all the lines from my `~/.bashrc` that appear to in any way relate to the Bash prompt:

```
# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
        # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
        # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
        # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
        color_prompt=yes
    else
        color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
```

How can I get my Bash prompt to appear as it did originally?

Comment: See [Bash prepends the symbol '@' to $PS1. How do I get rid of it?](http://askubuntu.com/a/767222/178692)

Comment: Excellent. Thank you! Please feel free to make that into an answer, so that I can mark it as correct and give you due credit :)

Comment: @steeldriver would you like to copy your Answer over? I was thinking about making a community-wiki copy of it, just so this Q has an A...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on a [meta discussion](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1396/how-do-we-feel-about-copying-answers-from-other-se-sites), I'm copying @steeldriver's perfectly good [AU answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767111/bash-prepends-the-symbol-to-ps1-how-do-i-get-rid-of-it/767222#767222) here:

---

You appear to have configured `readline` to enable *edit mode indication*. From [8.3.1 Readline Init File Syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Init-File-Syntax.html) of the Bash Reference Manual:

```
show-mode-in-prompt (Off)
       If set to On, add a character to the  beginning  of  the  prompt
       indicating  the  editing  mode:  emacs (@), vi command (:) or vi
       insertion (+).
```

You should be able to disable it in the current shell using

```
bind 'set show-mode-in-prompt off'
```

To disable it persistently, you will need to find where it is getting set, possibly your `~/.inputrc` or `/etc/inputrc` files.

Comment: Why is this a community wiki?

Comment: @John I didn't want to earn point from someone else's answer