# Where is the @ sign in front of my raspbian-bash-prompt coming from?

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, raspbian, prompt

There is @-sign in front of my raspbian-bash-prompt (headless) which I can't determine where it is coming from.

```
$ ssh pi@raspberrypi
Linux raspberrypi 4.14.98+ #1200 Tue Feb 12 20:11:02 GMT 2019 armv6l
(...)
@pi@raspberrypi:~$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf)
(...)
@pi@raspberrypi:~ $ echo $PS1
\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w \$\[\033[00m\]
```

It seems only to be there for the user pi and seems not to be part of the $PS1 variable, but it vanishes when i unset the variable.

```
@pi@raspberrypi:~ $ unset PS1
export PS1="prompt> "
@prompt> sudo su - lisa
lisa@raspberrypi:~ $ exit
logout
@prompt>
```

I temporarily (re)moved .profile, .bashrc, /etc/profile and /etc/bash.bashrc with the expected result except of the still leading @-sign

```
@-bash-4.4$
```

Another wild guess was, that it has to do with if I'm using an SSH-Key-File or if the user is part of the sudo group (because both is only the case for my pi user), but that's also not the case.
This raspbian-installation is in use for a couple of years and I played a lot around with it, so it is definitly possible that it has to do with something I changed.

Comment: Possibly [Spurious @ symbol at start of bash prompt in Debian Jessie](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/295151/spurious-symbol-at-start-of-bash-prompt-in-debian-jessie)

Comment: I can't believe it. Yes, thats the solution. `bind 'set show-mode-in-prompt off'` removes is directly and changing it in ~/.inputrc permanent.