# How to display the current mode of `vi` command-line editing (`set editing-mode vi`) in bash or tmux?

Tags: bash, terminal, tmux

I use `vi` command-line editing (`set editing-mode vi` in `~/.inputrc`) in Bash shells.

However, I find it frustrating, that I cannot see whether `vi` command-line editing is currently in command or input mode.

Is there someway to display the current mode of `vi` command-line editing in Bash or tmux?

Comment: Try `show-mode-in-prompt on` ... see related [Spurious @ symbol at start of bash prompt in Debian Jessie](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/295151/spurious-symbol-at-start-of-bash-prompt-in-debian-jessie)

Comment: @steeldriver - thank you. Do you know if I can set this option using `shopt`? Indeed, I can enable `vi` command-line editing using `shopt`.

Comment: TBH I don't know - aside from setting it via one of the `inputrc` files, the only way I know of is using the shell's `bind` built-in (`bind 'set show-mode-in-prompt on'`)

Comment: @steeldriver - also, do you know if all `vi` key-bindings apply to this `vi` mode? or where can I lookup the actual set of bindings?

Answer (score 3):

You can set the cursor style to reflect the mode by setting these in your `.inputrc`:

```
set editing-mode vi
set show-mode-in-prompt on
set vi-ins-mode-string \1\e[6 q\2
set vi-cmd-mode-string \1\e[2 q\2

# optionally:
# switch to block cursor before executing a command
set keymap vi-insert
RETURN: "\e\n"
```

This will give you a beam cursor in insert mode or a block cursor for normal mode.

For more see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42107711/52817

Comment: Thanks. What is a block cursor? Also, do you know if `show-mode-in-prompt` isn't available for Bash in macOS (can only get it to work on Debian).

Comment: Yes, on mac you need to update bash via homebrew first. block cursor is a rectangle instead of the beam.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `set show-mode-in-prompt on` to the readline configuration (`~/.inputrc` or `/etc/inputrc`)

If you want to toggle it directly in the shell you can do so via the `bind` built-in command:

```
bind 'set show-mode-in-prompt on'

bind 'set show-mode-in-prompt off'
```

See the related [Spurious @ symbol at start of bash prompt in Debian Jessie](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/295151/spurious-symbol-at-start-of-bash-prompt-in-debian-jessie)