# How to display the current mode of `vi` command-line editing (`set editing-mode vi`) in bash < 4.3

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, vim, readline

This question is related to [this other one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/533509/how-to-display-the-current-mode-of-vi-command-line-editing-set-editing-mode) but it is not a duplicate because I need a different solution for a different version of Bash.

I am a regular Vim user and I would like to change my command-line editing mode to Vi-like, instead of the default Emacs-like. This can be achieved by using the option `set editing-mode vi` in your `readline` configuration file `~/.inputrc`.

I would also like to be able to see the Vi mode I'm currently in (i.e. whether "insert" or "command"). In Bash >= 4.3 this is easily achieved with the option `set show-mode-in-prompt on`.

However, I'm stuck in a cluster where I have to use Bash 4.2. How can I view the Vi mode at all times? Preferably in the prompt, but it could also be something different like having cursors of different colors, or essentially anything else that allows me to quickly and visually determine the Vi mode.

Comment: I don't think you can. It [was introduced into `readline` in bash 4.3-alpha](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/CHANGES?h=bash-4.3#n831). vi-mode is a readline feature, so you'll have to rely on readline to report on it.

Comment: If you have access to git and the build tools in that cluster, you can clone the git repo and build a more recent version: https://savannah.gnu.org/git/?group=bash

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot for your quick reply. I do have access to Git. Do you think this would be a good solution? I am afraid that if I may use my own version of `bash` i may break stuff in unexpected ways.

Comment: If you use a recent version of bash for your interactive shell, I don't see what could break. If you're writing scripts, stick to the system bash version.

Comment: Just compile the new bash and set it's prefix/location in `~/bin` (create, if it does not exists ) and add that to your PATH if it is not included.